# How to split/ filter in iMacros for this name and time and the label?

Tags: imacros

Below the snippet of code HTML from a website.

```
<div class="list-mark">
   Bon Voyage Happyday · 1 week ago
</div>
<div class="list-mark">
   Jeann . · 2 days ago
</div>
<div class="list-mark">
   Billy . · 11 hours ago
</div>
<div class="list-mark">
   Totty Bonny · 7 hours ago
</div>
[and so on, repeat repeat]
```

and my iMacros scrip looks like bellow:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:list-mark EXTRACT=TXT
```

i need iMacros filtering csv for name and time and a unit of time; like this:

```
Column 1
Bon Voyage Happyday
Jeann 
Billy
Totti Bonny

Column 2
1
2
11
7

Column 3
week ago
days ago
hours ago
hours ago
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code may help you:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:list-mark EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/( \\.)* · /, '[EXTRACT]').replace(/(\d+) /, '$1[EXTRACT]');")
' SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT ...
```

Comment: ooh not good in result, cause some of name have dot (.) and some not.  if name only one word will add dot (.) on the web and if name 2 words then no dot (.)  -- i already edit the HTML above... please help Shugar thanks <br/>actually this is my real script [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw-ge5kOFyp2WE81S2JPRFBBelE) <br/> and from that your EVAL colum name all values same even repeat 20 times or more..?

thanks you

Comment: still not good @Shugar.. look like this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ub9pyladuw9l6x/17.38.46%202016-08-05.jpg?dl=0)  
and this is the script actually [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/77zwukpko4mcpny/thisScript.iim?dl=0)